# Laravel Notifications mark each as read

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

How can I mark each notification for a user as read, currently I do mark all as read like this:

Route

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'notification', 'as' => 'notification.'], function () {
    Route::delete('destroy/{userID}}', ['as' => 'destroy', 'uses' => 'NotificationController@destroy']);
});
```

Controller

```
    public function destroy($userID)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($userID);
        $user->unreadNotifications->map(function($n) {
            $n->markAsRead();
        });

        return back();
    }
```

Form

```
<form method="post" action="notification/destroy/{{ Auth::id() }}">
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <button type="submit">Mark as read.</button>
</form>
```

Comment: why your route url and form url are different?

Comment: @PankajMakwana sorry missed to copy the prefix in the question, updated now

Comment: Pass the notification id as parameter and then test if the given unreaded notification matchs the passed id !

Comment: @Maraboc ok I pass the Parameter, but would do I check if the given unreadable notfication Matches the id, could you share Code?

Comment: ok before that in the form have you the notification ID ??

Comment: @Maraboc I do not have neough Reputation to create one, I have the notfication uuid as a hidden field like this `<input type="hidden" name="notification_uuid" value="{{ $notification->id }}">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have in your form some thing like this :

```
<form method="post" action="notification/destroy/{{ Auth::id() }}">
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="notification_uuid" value="{{ $notification->id }}">
    <button type="submit">Mark as read.</button>
</form>
```

All you need to do is add a test in the map method like this :

```
public function destroy($userID, , Request $request)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($userID);
    $user->unreadNotifications->map(function($n) use($request) {
        if($n->id == $request->get('notification_uuid')){
            $n->markAsRead();
        }
    });

    return back();
}
```

Comment: hi thanks, strange the notification_uuid is undefined inside the map function but outside ist defined

Comment: The request variable is undefined in the map function

Comment: Nice seems to work, can you explain what excatly the use Statement does here please `use($request) {
`?

Comment: It tells the anonymous function that there is a variable outside your scope that i need to use in the statements of the function ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
public function destroy($userID)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($userID);
    $user->unreadNotifications->get()->map(function($n) {
        $n->markAsRead();
    });

    return back();
}
```